# Redirect to a specific wiki js auth strategy

Tags: next.js, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c, wiki.js

I have a wiki js app with 2 azure AD auth strategies: strat1 & strat2 under the /login url that shows me the option for the 2 strategies and when I choose one of them it redirects me to the azure auth.

The second strategy is an Azure AD B2C authentication that I have in common with a next js app, that has a button that redirects me to the wiki js app.

I want to know if its possible to be redirected directly to the strat2 in order to have a SSO between the 2 apps, instead of being redirected to the login and having to choose the strat2

Is this possible? How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from the wiki js github.

We need to use `/login/<strategy-uuid>` where `<strategy-uuid>` is the id of the strategy that can be found in the wiki admin area.